# how to restrict the URL while login with admin panel in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project the front end and back end in same laravel project, when admin is login in this case the if it has active session the admin user goes to front end of project i want to restrict the URL the admin user never go to front end while his session is active help me .

```
 Route::get ('/shopping','FrontendController@index')->name('shopping.home');
```

This URL i want to restrict while active the admin user session.
other routes for front end

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['frontlogin']], function() {
    Route::get ('/shopping/product','FrontendController@product')->name('shopping.product');
    Route::get ('/shopping/login','FrontendController@login')->name('shopping.login');
}
```

Middelware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(empty(Session::has('frontSession'))) {
        return redirect()->route('shopping.login');
    }
    return $next($request);     
}
```

Comment: Which URL do you want to restrict? means all the `/shopping/` URL or only `index` method URL?

Comment: yes  /shopping  url

Comment: you want the stop the admin from reaching those 3 routes?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya if user has authenticated as admin while his active session in this case if he want to go to shopping page then  i want to restrict that URL in other case it should be normal

Comment: @lagbox no it is already restricted

Comment: @lagbox He can not understand your question. But he needs to restrict admin

Comment: @lagbox if i am login as admin to admin panel this is my active session if i want to access this url in my current browser right now it should be accessed and the user should be logged in into front end because session is already active

Comment: please show your `frontlogin` middleware, you will have to adjust it most likely to allow the admin to reach it ... I understand what you are looking for now

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(empty(Session::has('frontSession'))){
           return redirect()->route('shopping.login');
          }

        return $next($request);     
    } @lagbox

Comment: how do you determine that the user is an admin ... is it a session variable or an attribute on the User model ?

Answer (score 1):

check config/auth.php file.

you can define custom auth guards there. just define your guard names, drivers and providers there.

```
'guards' => [
    'frontlogin' => [
        'driver' => 'session', 
        'provider' => 'users', 
    ],
],
```

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'users'
    ],
],
```

You may check Laravel Authentication [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Comment: side note: you can remove the `table` key from the `users` provider, that key is used for the `database` driver

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you are logging in the `admin` you will need to add your session key that your `frontlogin` middleware is checking for, `frontSession`:

```
Session::set('frontSession', true);
```

Or you will need to come up with a different mechanism to filter out who can not reach those routes protected by `frontlogin`.

Comment: please describe more

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh you would have to provide more information about how you are determining a user is an admin

Comment: yes i have one filed in user table "role" while registration the the default role should be insisted  as "Customer" otherwise other admin should be approved the user as admin

Comment: and how does that role relate to this whole `frontlogin` thing? and what role is the admin?